# Rails 5 model a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design, many-to-many

I have two models, project and users and I want to connect them as follows:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  has_many :members, class_name: "User"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
end
```

Migration looks like this.

```
class AddReferencesToProject < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :projects, :owner
    add_foreign_key :projects, :users, column: :owner_id, primary_key: :id
  end
end
```

I did this migration for members_id but I want it to have more then one user_id:

```
class AddMembersReferencesToProject < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :projects, :members
    add_foreign_key :projects, :users, column: :members_id, primary_key: :id
  end
end
```

Do I need to make a many_to many :through association? I´m stuck on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `has_many :through` makes sense for your many-to-many association. (I don't tend to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, but that's mostly a personal preference.)

It might look something like:

#### User

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                       :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at               :datetime         not null
#  updated_at               :datetime         not null
#
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many    :owned_projects, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many    :project_members, foreign_key: :member_id
  has_many    :projects, through: :project_members
end
```

#### Project

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id                       :integer          not null, primary key
#  owner_id                 :integer
#  created_at               :datetime         not null
#  updated_at               :datetime         not null
#
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :owner, class_name: "User"
  has_many    :project_members
  has_many    :members, through: :project_members
end
```

#### ProjectMember

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: project_members
#
#  id                       :integer          not null, primary key
#  member_id                :integer
#  project_id               :integer
#  created_at               :datetime         not null
#  updated_at               :datetime         not null
#
class ProjectMembers < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :member, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to  :project
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked fine. So I get an entry for every project_member relation. Isn't that bloating the DB?

Comment: Is using a join table to relate two other tables "bloating the database"? No, it is using a relational database the way it is intended to be used and, in this particular case, following a pattern that is common in Ruby on Rails.